# Counting images in an MS-ACCESS 2003 column

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

Warning - Newbie ahead

I have a table with one column that has an OLE/object format with images in it.

Some cells have images and some don't.

I want to count the number of images in the column.

I thought of maybe to add a column that will have a formula that will detect if the cell with the image is empty or full and then export the table to Excel and count the result.

I don't know how to do create a column with a formula

Maybe there is another way of doing what I want to do.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think this formula might work:

```
SUM(Iif([image_column] IS NULL, 0, 1))
```

You'll have to GROUP BY your other columns if you have other fields in your query.

Answer (score 0):

I am such a noob! I forgot that I can use SQL to query an ACCESS table.

This just works

select count(image) from table where 2011=1